# Updating Mongodb Document Relationally

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a mongo database with the with a users collection and a followers collection. The Users collection stores a name, username and profile_pic file location in Amazon s3. The Followers collection stores the users_id and information of the followee(person their following) including their _id, username, and profile_pic file. While the _id and profile_pic will never change, the username can if users chooses to. Therefore, the document wouldn't be updated with the most current username. This isn't a problem in mysql because its relational. Being new to Mongodb, how do people solve this sort of issue? If I need to get all 300 of a users friends or more it doesn't seem reasonable to me make 300 calls to get the individual username. Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can store user profile and followers in one users collection like this:

```
{
_id: 'T4Y...AC', // base64-encoded ObjectId
name: 'Rick',
profile: { ... username, profile_pic , etc. ... },

followers: ["T4Y...AD", "T4Y...AF", "T4Y...AI"]

}
```

Comment: That is a possibility, i'm thinking of staying away from embedding them because I want maintain the highest amount of flexibility when manipulating the data. Regardless how does that solve the problem, if a user updates their username then it doesn't correspond with the document. Because mongo isn't relational then I would get the wrong username if the user changed theirs? How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: I changed structure.  you can take only _id of user and this way you do not need sync.

Comment: If you are creating social network using mongodb . there is very good design schema in **mongodb applied design patterns** book for realize this.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to mongo coming from a mysql background, how would I get the users' data with their id? In a person's follower's list I still need to show the follower's username.

Comment: Just db.collection.find ("_id":"T4Y...AD")

Comment: so If I have 500 followers I have to call db.collection.find 500 times?

Comment: First query you will get user profile data user name and other data of user and same time flowwers ids.  Second query you will get flowwer data

Comment: No just 2 query. As i say my last comment

Comment: 1. var user=db.users.find({"name":"somebody"});
after first query you will get user profile data and followers user ids.
2.  db.users.find({"_id":{"$in":user. followers}});
and using user followers ids you can get all followers data using "in"  keyword

Comment: That last part is what I needed, thanks man I'll test it out tonight but accept the answer now bc the effort, I appreciate it!

Comment: last question, are their any limits on the $in operator? If I have say, 5000 followers what is the operation speed looking like? Does this solution scale?

Comment: If you will have great follower list. it should read little topic mongodb ** applied design patterns ** book- social network pattern.   there written that. when you change your profile data. you need run background  task for sync data in  all followers list.